# PHP Mysqli show the result of count sum

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, count

I have the following code. It works correctly on phpmyadmin. What i have to change to show the sum of SUM_OF_NULLs?

```
$query = "
    SELECT (
        (CASE WHEN `name_kid`='X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `name_kid`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `name_kid`='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `bday`='0000-00-00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `born_city`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `born_country`='X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `topos_katoikias`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `ithageneia`='0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `amea_text`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `date_eis`='0000-00-00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `date_exit`='0000-00-00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `sur_fysikos`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `name_fysikos`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `ithag_fysikos`='0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `sur_mother_fys`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `name_mother_fys`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `ithag_mother_fys`='0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `sur_anad`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `name_anad`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `sur_mother_anad`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `name_mother_anad`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `city_anad`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `sur_thet`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `name_thet`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `sur_thet_mother`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `name_thet_mother`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `city_thet`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `ar_apof`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `date_apof`='0000-00-00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `protodikio`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `case_close`='0000-00-00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `kid_thetos_sur`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `kid_thetos_name`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `arithmos_mitrwou`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `code_forea_filox`='00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `ar_forea_filox`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `code_forea_fakelos`='00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `sxetikoi_fakeloi`='00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN `sur_kid`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    ) AS SUM_OF_NULLs FROM `fakelos-final`
";
if ($result2 = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    printf("Total: %d \n", $result2->SUM($result2));

    /* free result set */
    $result2->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `sum` function of MySQL. That way you only get back one row, containing the sum.

```
$query = "
    SELECT SUM(
        (CASE WHEN `name_kid`='X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        ...
        +(CASE WHEN `sur_kid`='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    ) AS SUM_OF_NULLs FROM `fakelos-final`
";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query) && $row = $result->fetch_array()) {

    printf("Total: %d \n", $row['SUM_OF_NULLs']);

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}
```

Comment: It returns Warning: mysqli_result::fetch_array(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_result in ERROR